# wireless usb hub with the hub on the computer side - does this exist?

Tags: usb, wireless-networking, hub

I'm looking for what is effectively a wireless usb hub, but where the "hubbing" part takes place on the computer-side. In other words, something like this:

http://www.iogear.com/product/GUWH104KIT/

Except rather than all four "terminating" slots being connected, having 4 small "wireless terminals" so that the devices can be placed all over a room instead of all within reach of the wireless usb hub

Does such a product exist?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the kit you've linked to can do that already -- if you have multiple "hubs".  If you look, what the kit consists of is two different products:

1. A [USB dongle](http://www.iogear.com/product/GUWA100U/) called a "host adapter"; this plugs into your computer and provides the "Wireless USB" connectivity.
2. A [4-port hub](http://www.iogear.com/product/GUWH104/) that connects via "Wireless USB" to the host adapter.

Since they are sold separately, you could have multiple hubs connect wirelessly to the same host adapter.  These products are "Certified Wireless USB", operate on the Multi-band OFDM Ultra Wide Band (UWB) 1.0 specification, and should be interoperable with other "Certified Wireless USB" products.  Wireless USB can allow multiple computers to share devices, but device access is one-at-a-time.  There's no indication that the hub is "paired" to a specific adapter.

*Edit: Actually, I may be wrong; the IOgear site lists pricing for the kit and the adapter, but not the hub.  I believe this demonstrates a marketing strategy of "sell one adapter with every hub, and extra adapters as needed".*

[image]

Comment: ideally i'd like to avoid buying 4 for 4 usb devices as they're over 100 bucks each. What I'm looking for is really a 5-piece kit: a usb dongle, and 4 wireless usb plugs i can distribute around the room

Comment: @mala: yep.  good luck!  tho note that current pricing puts the adapter-only for $100, so presumably the hub by itself is only $30, if you could find it for sale by itself.